# ctypes c++ function returns array of unknown size

Tags: c++, python, arrays, ctypes

I have a c++ function that accepts a Pointer to an array of known size as input and returns an array of size that cannot be determined until the function completes its processing of data. How do I call the c++ function, passing the first array and receive the results as a second array?

I currently do something similar to this:

PYTHON:

```
def callout(largeListUlonglongs):
    cFunc = PyDLL("./cFunction.dll").processNumbers

    arrayOfNums = c_ulonglong * len(largeListUlonglongs)
    numsArray = arrayOfNums()

    for x in xrange(len(largeListUlonglongs)):
        numsArray[x] = long(largeListUlonglongs[x])

    cFunc.restype = POINTER(c_ulonglong * len(largeListUlonglongs))

    returnArray = cFunc(byref(numsArray)).contents

    return returnArray
```

This works so long as the returnArray is of the same size as the numsArray. If it is smaller then the empty elements of the array are filled with 0's. If the returned array is larger than the results get cut off once the array elements are filled.

If it helps, the structure of the returned array contains the size of the returned array as its first element.

Thanks for the help in advance...

Comment: *"If it is smaller then the empty elements of the array are filled with 0's."* That's pure coincidence based on whether that memory is allocated and zero'd. It could just as easily segfault. ctypes isn't copying the return array into a new buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Normally it is preferable to get the caller to allocate the buffer. That way the caller is in a position to deallocate it also. However, in this case, only the callee knows how long the buffer needs to be. And so the onus passes to the callee to allocate the buffer.

But that places an extra constraint on the system. Since the callee is allocating the buffer, the caller cannot deallocate it unless they share the same allocator. That can actually be arranged without too much trouble. You can use a shared allocator. There are a few. Your platform appears to be Windows, so for example you can use `CoTaskMemAlloc` and `CoTaskMemFree`. Both sides of the interface can call those functions.

The alternative is to keep allocation and deallocation together. The caller must hold on to the pointer that the callee returns. When it has finished with the buffer, usually after copying it into a Python structure, it asks the library to deallocate the memory.

Answer (score 2):

David gave you useful advice on the memory management concerns. I would generally use the simpler strategy of having a function in the library to free the allocated buffer. The onus is on the caller to prevent memory leaks.

To me your question seems to be simply about casting the result to the right pointer type. Since you have the length in index 0, you can set the result type to a `long long` pointer. Then get the size so you can cast the result to the correct pointer type.

```
def callout(largeListUlonglongs):
    cFunc = PyDLL("./cFunction.dll").processNumbers
    cFunc.restype = POINTER(c_ulonglong)

    arrayOfNums = c_ulonglong * len(largeListUlonglongs)
    numsArray = arrayOfNums(*largeListUlonglongs)   

    result = cFunc(numsArray)
    size = result[0]
    returnArray = cast(result, POINTER(c_ulonglong * size))[0]

    return returnArray
```