# Get an array that creates in C-function from Python3 with ctypes

Tags: python, c++, c

For instance, I have a very strange function in C-language, something like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

extern "C"{
int f(int lenA, int *a, int** b){
    int n = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<lenA; i++){
        n+= (a[i] > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    }
    int tmpB [n];
    int ind = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<lenA; i++){
        if(a[i]>0){
            tmpB[ind] = a[i];
            ind++;
        }
    }
    *b = tmpB;
    return n;
};
}
```

If I want to call it from Python ang get `b` array without preliminary knoweledge of the size, how it is necessary to do it in Python if in C I will do next:

```
int a = {1, 2, 3, -7, -9, 100};
int *b;
int lenA = 6;
int nB = f(lenA, a, &b);
```

In Python I tried something like this, but faces `segmentation fault`

```
import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np

def _np_ptr(np_array):
    return ct.c_void_p(np_array.ctypes.data)

def pf(lenA, a, b):
    lib = ct.CDLL('test.so')
    pfun = lib.f
    a = np.array(a, dtype=np.int32)
    b = ct.POINTER(ct.c_int)()
    pfun.argtypes = (ct.c_void_p, ct.POINTER(ct.c_int))
    pfun.restype = ct.c_int
    n = pfun(lenA, _np_ptr(a), b)
    return b, n
a = [1, 2, 3, -7, -9, 100]
b, n = pf(6, a, None)
```

To be honest, I have no idea how to do this without any modification of C-code.

Comment: if `n` becomes very large, then this C code could easily blow the stack at this line: `int tmpB [n];`. Are you sure you cannot change the C code?

Comment: @gnodab, yep, unfortunately I cannot :(

Comment: There are other weird things in the C code. For instance why allocate `n` when you're only looping over `lenA`? Here: `for(int i=0; i<lenA; i++){`. This implies that you do know the size of 'b', and that you potentially could change '**b' to '*b'

Comment: @gnodab, in my case there is no problem with stack, i've got enough resources. It is necessary for me understand how to call such functions in Python and get ```b``` array

Comment: @gnodab, I just wrote a strange code just for demonstration my question. In reality I have a function that creates an array and I don't know the real length of this array. Of course, in this context it is better to change ```**b --> *b```, I totaly agree with you. But again this code just for demonstration. The main question ```How to get the array that creates in C-code without knowing in advance its length?```

Comment: I understand. But I think with your example you have an out of bounds error, which is potentially causing the segfault. I'm not sure how to move data through c types without know the size. But I'd like to make sure the C side isn't causing your problems first. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16023614/13253198) help?

Comment: @gnobad, I checked my real C-code in C-compiler with different input data and I don't have an out of bounds error. No, ufortunately that post doesn't help me. Or I couldn't imply it right

Comment: The `int**b` pointer is assigned `tmpB`, but `tmpB` is no longer valid when the function exits. How does this not crash? what is the point of `b`?

Comment: @MarkNunberg, because I call f with ```** b``` and it means that after function execution b will exist after that

Comment: Also, you pass in a vector of length 6, such that `lenA` is 6. But then `n` would be calculated as 4 for your inputs. So when you loop to fill in `tmpB` you will have an out of bounds error. `ind` is going to go to 6. But you have only set size of `tmpB` to a length of 4

Comment: @gnodab, why ```ind``` will be 6, I don't  agree, ```ind``` will be 4 too, because it increase only if item of a is > 0. Incremention of ```ind``` is in the same part as initialazing ```tmpB```

Comment: My mistake... missed the if

Comment: @gnodab, it is ok :)